# Chef cannot upload

Tags: chef-infra

I am learning the basics of chef.

Basically what I have done in my windows env is that I have created a folder on my desktop called chef

In this directory, I have a folder called cookbooks, my knife.rb and my pem key.

In my cookbooks, [I did a git clone.](https://github.com/learn-chef/learn_chef_iis.git)

Now in my directory (C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\chef), I did a knife upload cookbook learn_chef_iis.

However,it gives me a

**ERROR: Could not find cookbook learn_chef_iis in your cookbook path, skipping i
t**

My ruby file is as below:

```
# See http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html for more information on knife configuration options

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "leexhhadrian"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/leexhhadrian.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/chefexampleadrian"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The knife.rb and pem file should go in their own sub folder, Desktop/chef/.chef/